# How do you check what toolbox tab is currently open?

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

Can you know which tab is currently opened in the blockly toolbox?
If so, can anyone show me an example or code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

The toolbox contains a Closure UI [Tree](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.ui.tree.TreeControl).

To get the name of the most recent tab while accessing a minimum set of private members:

```
var tree = workspace.getToolbox().tree_;  
var selectedItem = tree.getSelectedItem();
if (selectedItem) {
  var itemText = selectedItem.getText();
} else {
  console.log('no item selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by doing trial and error things!

[workspace here].toolbox_.lastCategory_.html_.privateDoNotAccessOrElseSafeHtmlWrappedValue_

stores a string whith the most recent selected tab, and

workspace.toolbox_.lastCategory_.selected_

gives a boolean which lets you know if the last selected tab is currently selected.